# Can somebody please explain to me this css code

Tags: html, css

Hi I am new to css and I have came across this text underline animation, I couldn't understand how it works. If I just take something out of this code it just stops working. Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
body a {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
body a:visited {
  color: white;
}
body a:hover {
  color: white;
}
body a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
body a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's really important here are the pseudo-elements ":after" and ":before" (although this last one not present here).

This part here is what makes it come to life:

```
body a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

You see, basically you're looking at the declaration of properties of an element's pseudo element. (You might want to dig in a bit into CSS-CSS3).

It states that after triggering the hover event on an anchor that is a child of body it will make its pseudo element have a bottom border of 2 pixels of width, with a white solid color and a transition of 0.4 seconds.

We can tell by the other declarations that the width of the pseudo-element is 0% in its initial state and after hovering it goes to 100% with a transition (making it go from left to right as seen in the example).

There's much things to consider in this CSS code but you should really learn the basics!

Comment: I see, but what about the content, position, bottom and left what does those properties have to do with the animation, If you take out any of them the animation will not even appear!

Answer (score 1):

An `:after` psuedo CSS means that another "virtual" element is appended after the selected element

the psuedo element appended on `a:after` is a simple element with bottom `border` but is without width (`0%`)

the `transition` property on that element means, that all properties of that element when changed will be animated

so...

when you hover the element (stated in `body a:hover:after`) - the width of that "virtual" element is set to 100% - and the animation takes place

Answer (score 0):

This line creates the animation:
transition: 0.4s;

You will notice that the body a:hover:after rule has a width of 100%. Well, that transition property tells the render engine that there is an animation to be performed on any property that has a value change between the normal and hover state.

When you hover, the render engine reads that you want to set the width property to 100%. Before hover it was set at 0%. Transition says, "ok, on hover, animate the width property from 0 to 100% over a period of 4 tenths of a second.

This will be true of any properties that differ between the hover and non-hover state. In other words, you could animate more than one property at a time so long as the two states define the same property with different values.